# jquery selector fails when adding styles (multiple css classes)

Tags: jquery, css

I want to log "test" when the mouse enters a image with "mytrigger"-class. The image may also have a class called "dupimg".

my html

```
...
<img src="img.png" class="dupimg mytrigger" />
...
```

my stylesheet.css

```
.dupimg{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    height: 120px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    border: 1px dotted;
}
```

my js snippet

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mytrigger").mouseenter(function() {
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

This does, for some reason, not work (no "test" messages in console). But if i change the first class of the image to something else it's all good (e.g. img src="img.png" class="dupimg_a mytrigger"). I't also works if I remove the css for .dupimg. So my question is why does it not work with css attached? How do I get it to work?

Using jquery 1.10.2.

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/QYT5c/

Comment: because you're floating left, your image probably doesn't have a height associated so you aren't technically doing a mouseenter.  Try assigning fixed dimensions or doing a clear:both after the element and I'll bet it will work.

Comment: @Rooster -- Nice catch..probably causing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a

```
clear:both;
```

after the img.dupimg element to clear the associated float rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
your code is working fine, unless you are trying to check in ie7
<http://jsfiddle.net/nyshangal/xQQY6/>
```

Comment: Nah fails in both Firefox 22.0 (for ubuntu) and Chromium 28.0.